# NSData( contentsOfURL: url ) return nil

Tags: swift, null, nsdata

```
var fileu = strData.objectForKey("url") as String
var fileurl:NSURL = NSURL(string: fileu)!

var dataFromUrl:NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileurl)

println(dataFromUrl);
```

When I tested the url in the browser, the url is working.
But in

```
var dataFromUrl:NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileurl)
```

return nil.

```
fileu is "http://localhost/Web/TMS_ReadFile.ashx?FileID=0"
```

when I dropped it in the address bar, it actually download .
Did anyone face this kind of issue before? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you running it against simulator or on device. If on device it will look for web server running on the device and will fail.